# MySQL SQL Retrieve Number of Computers Running a Particular Operating System Sorted by Most Popular First

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble constructing an SQL Statement. I have a Computer Table and an Operating System Table. The Operating System table is a look-up table.

[image]

I don't have a clue about how to write the query. Any help would be appreciated.

Retrieve the number of computers running each operating system, sorted by the most popular operating system at the top.

Edit:

Yes, this is homework. I am learning MySQL, JQuery, and XSLT/XML in school. I am an expert with Microsoft Access. I use Access at work primarily. If I had to figure this out for work, I would write a VBA function, or design a report where I could group by Operating System and then count the number of computers running each operating system.

I have a feeling that I need to use Group By and an Aggregate Function but I am still not sure how to construct the statement.

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

I figured it out. Thanks for your help Clay. Here is the code:

```html
SELECT tblplatform.txtplatform, Count(tblcomputers.txtComputerName) AS CountOftxtComputerName
FROM tblplatform RIGHT JOIN tblcomputers ON tblplatform.idtblplatform = tblcomputers.tblplatform_idtblplatform
GROUP BY tblplatform.txtplatform
ORDER BY Count(tblcomputers.txtComputerName) DESC;
```

Comment: What have you already done? Can you show us your desired result. And, please give some sample data in each of your tables.

Comment: Unless you show some minimal understanding of the problem and what effort you have done so far to write this query yourself and what particular errors/problems you have faced, this kind of questions are considered off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks dotNet. I will keep that in mind. But, just to let you know, I always attempt to find the answer before I post a question. And I did post the solution. When I said I didn't have a clue as to how to construct the SQL, that is what I meant. That is why I didn't post what I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description of the problem, you will need to JOIN the two tables, use an aggregate function (COUNT, which requires GROUP BY to function) to determine the number of computer rows associated with each platform row, and then ORDER BY the results. [Check out the reference for MySQL SELECT.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)
Pay special attention to keywords: COUNT, JOIN, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck in your studies.